# Make a desktop shortcut of Chrome Extensions

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, .desktop, shortcuts, chrome-extension

There is this particular chat app called **Line** but it does not provide Linux version. But thankfully the developer made a chrome extension. In the past, extensions were integrated with chrome://apps so it was very easy to add shortcut to desktop. Line also does not provide the web version like WhatsApp or Microsoft Teams so cannot add shortcut directly. Any help would be highly appreciated. Line extension (top right corner) does not show up on chrome app list:

[image: Line extension (top right corner) does not show up on chrome app list]

I'm running Chrome 87.0.4280.88 on Ubuntu 20.04.01 64 bit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you really would have to do is get the Chrome Extension ID of the app and then add it to a .desktop file.

Goto `chrome://extensions` and that will bring them all up.  Look for the app in question:

[image: Details of a Chrome extension called LINE. Its ID is "ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc".]

Then add that ID with a `/index.html` at the end of it to the command that Google Chrome will launch.  For example, a "Line Chat.desktop" with the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Line Chat
Comment=Line Chat
Exec=google-chrome --app="chrome-extension://ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc/index.html"
Icon=
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

You can always find an icon you like and add it to the `Icon=` line.

The `--app=<url>` argument tells Chrome to launch in app mode, hiding UI elements.  If you want the extension page to open in an ordinary tab, use something like

```
Exec=google-chrome "chrome-extension://ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc/index.html"
```

instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This definitely worked! But one thing, I couldn't launch the .desktop right away. I had to copy the file to /usr/share/applications and the launch it from app launcher. But it will open Line on a Chrome window with tabs, not as individual app. So i made a shortcut again directly from Chrome. Now it's perfect. Thank you very much!

I'm sorry if my comment doesn't make sense or have grammatical error here and there. English not my first language.

Comment: @FarhanHafizh `~/.local/share/applications` is enough. Create if not exists already. Also, the icon can be found from `find ~ -iname '*line*'`.

Comment: I need this for mac and windows as well

Comment: @Alexandralarosa If you are wanting just a short cut to the Google Chrome apps you have installed, just bring up your Google Chrome browser, go to `chrome://apps`, then right-click the app and choose Create Shortcut.  It will make you a desktop, start menu and quick launch shortcut for whatever app you want.

Comment: @Terrance No I want to go to `chrome-extension://ilfhfhffaipnjdlbgfkeljalig/app.html` from desktop for each OS.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the URL="..." must point to a valid file.  Not all extensions have a index.html in the root folder.  Sometimes you have to "dig" a bit to find them.